# Comment box half cutoff

Tags: facebook, comments, height, cut

My Facebook comment box is cut off half way. I saved this as HTML and opened it with Safari, Chrome and Firefox but they're all half cutoff. How do I fix that?

I have been trying for a long time and cannot get it to work. For simplicity's sake, I am using only the necessary code for the comment box:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id))
                    return;
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=170045126459927";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, the page won't stop showing the loading sign.

Comment: How do you think showing us some copy&pasted _example code_ will help us analyze the _real_ problem? Post a link to your site please, if you want to get help with this problem here.

Comment: @CBroe I highly recommend reading this post(Could we please be a-bit nicer to new users) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users. Dont you notice this is probably his first question, Rather than doing a -1 please be patient with the user. Its a first time for every one and we need to welcome people in to this community and not be too tough on them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your CSS file:

If you are using a Pluggin, you have to quit all the codes like

```
. facebook-comment { width: 95px !important; }
```

These codes are setting-up automatically by the plugin and don't allow you to settle the facebook comment box as you want.

Once you have done that, you can create a  in your PHP console and then adding this class in your CSS file to customize your box as you want.